# Cannot compare two date in while loop

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I was having problem when using "Date" property.
My class here:

```
public bool ChuyenDSChamCong()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dta = DSChamCong();
        if (dta == null)
            return false;
        foreach (DataRow r in dta.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                string sql = "delete FROM tk_dlchamcong where MD5(CONCAT(ma_chamcong,ma_nv, tg_check)) = md5('" + r["CardID"] + r["StaffID"] + r["TransDT"].ToString() + "')";
                MYSQLDB.query(sql);
                while (((DateTime)r["TransDT"]).Date == (DateTime.Today).Date)
                {
                    string sql1 = "INSERT INTO tk_dlchamcong(ID,ma_chamcong, ma_nv, tg_check)values(md5('" + r["CardID"] + r["StaffID"] + r["TransDT"].ToString() + "'),'" + r["CardID"] + "', '" + r["StaffID"] + "', '" + r["TransDT"] + "')";
                    MYSQLDB.query(sql1);
                }
            }
            catch {
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch { }
    return false;
}
```

I cannot use Date() property, it accept with Date only. But when I debug it show like this and jump to catch error.

It cannot compare, `r["TransDT"]` is `DateTime`. Here is image show error.

[image]

Updated: r["TransDT"] is object{string} in database has values: `11/11/2015 18:03:11`

I was format this with query like:
`FORMAT(TransDT,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') as TransDT from Transact`

Error when debug:

[Animate screenshot gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imB2m.gif)

Comment: Well, obviously, `r["TransDT"]` is not of type DateTime, can you verify what type it actually is? `Debug.WriteLine(r["TransDT"].GetType().FullName);` (assuming it cannot be `null`)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen DateTime though is nullable as far as I'm aware. So if null it should be DBNULL if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: Also, are you **really** gong to insert rows until the next day? Your while-loop doesn't advance `r`, you're going to keep doing the same thing over and over and over again until the one thing that does change has changed enough, and that is `DateTime.Today`. Also, `DateTime.Today` is already just the date, you don't need `.Date` as well.

Comment: Why you use `while` if you actually want to use `if`?

Comment: `DBNull` is not of type `DateTime`, you cannot unbox that to `DateTime`.

Comment: that is what I meant. null would be ok but from the commands it would not be null but DBNull then (sry if I was writing what I meant unclear)

Comment: What is the value of `r["TransDT"]`, you have shown the error but not the value.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I'm was updated in question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The value could be `null`(`DBNull.Value`), you coudl try to cast it to a `DateTime?` with the [`as`-operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx). When the cast fails you get a `Nullable<DateTime>` with `HasValue=false`:

```
DateTime? TransDT = r["TransDT"] as DateTime?;
if(TransDT.HasValue && TransDT.Value.Date == DateTime.Today)
{
    // ...
}
```

You don't need a `while`, an `if` is sufficient since you have a single `DataRow`.

Comment: You can also do: `if (TransDT == DateTime.Today)`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: right, i just wanted to make it clearer what a `DateTime?` is and that it has a `HasValue` and `Value` property. Otherwise it wouldn't be so clear why i use it here.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I tried this code. But `TransDT` values always is null.